# Firebase functions - compile typescript code before running emulators:start

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-tools

I have a Firebase project setup with `/functions` directory, where all the source code is getting compiled from `/src` to the `/dist` directory.

The question is: how to configure Firebase in such way that it will run `tsc` command each time before starting the Local Emulator Suite? I wonder if there is a similar property to `functions.predeploy` in `firebase.json` config, but for the Local Emulator Suite:

```json
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix functions run build"
    ],
    // something like this:
    "preemulator": [
      "npm --prefix functions run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is a `build` script from `package.json`:

```json
  "scripts": {
    // ...
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
  }
```

Comment: i think you can prepend the build command to the emulator start command

Comment: @NaveenKashyap I'd rather prefer not to change the command itself, same as I don't have to prepend the build command to the deploy command because of a `predeploy` hook. Currently the only way to solve the issue I see is to create a separate script which will build the project and then start the emulator

Comment: You could just write your own shell script that runs `npm run build` before executing the Firebase CLI.

Comment: @DougStevenson yeah I know, that's how it works for now, just wanted to know if there is a bit cleaner solution. Thanks for the comment!